# Primefaces upgrade to 4.0 (or 5.0) version cause Property not found on type

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

After have upgraded primefaces form 2.2.1 to 4.0 version (same with 5.0 version), when navigating to /abtest.xhtml page deployed on tomcat 7, getting the following error :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /abtest.xhtml: Property 'onFlowProcess' not found on type com.web.faces.abtest.ABTestWizard
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)
```

In pom.xml have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

In abtest.xhtml have:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
...
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
...
     <p:wizard id="abtestwizard" widgetVar="wiz" flowListener="#{abwizard.onFlowProcess}" showStepStatus="false" effect="false" showNavBar="false" onback="jQuery('.equalHeight').equalHeights();" onnext="jQuery('.equalHeight').equalHeights();">
```

And in com.web.faces.abtest.ABTestWizard:

```
@Component("abwizard")
@Scope("view")
public class ABTestWizard implements Serializable {
...
    public String onFlowProcess(org.primefaces.event.FlowEvent event) {  ...
    }
...
}
```

The flowListener attribute of the p:wizard tag seems to be set properly, so no idea why this error occurs.

Would appreciate any any idea or hint to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your pom.xml as well?

```
     <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
```

You also might be missing some imports in your bean. Which imports do you have listed?